# Setting Content-Type header in axios causes no data is sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, axios

I'm using axios to POST data to WebApi and I'm trying to set Content-Type to application/json, but when I'm adding headers to config no data is sent.
My axios request:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',},
    url: `${URL}/Signin`,
    data: user  
});
```

and it results with request:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:50644/api/Signin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50644
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:3000/Signin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

When I remove headers from my axios request all is ok, but Content Type is wrong.

```
POST http://localhost:50644/api/Signin HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:50644
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://localhost:3000/Signin
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
{
    "Name": "test",
    "Password": "test"
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your first request is a CORS preflight check (OPTIONS). Your second is a POST.

Comment: But my browser dosen't make second request.
The response I get from server is:
`{Message: "The origin 'http://localhost:3000' is not allowed."}`

Comment: Which likely means your OPTIONS preflight check is failing and your server does not support CORS. This is a CORS issue - there are *tonnnes* of helpful answers here on SO to help you with that.

Comment: My server is .NET Web API, and I have CORS configured: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS`

Comment: Please include the entire HTTP response to your OPTIONS request.

Comment: `{Message: "The origin 'http://localhost:3000' is not allowed."}`

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure without knowing what the data structure of `user` looks like, but I imagine you need to do `data: JSON.stringify(user)` to turn `user` into JSON format.

Comment: User is "stringified".
`const user = JSON.stringify({
                Name: login,
                Password: password
            },null,"\t");`